# Drush pm-update: How can I stop it from trying to update more recent dev releases?

Tags: drush

I'm using drush 5 to update the modules on my site.  Usually it works great.  However, when I have downloaded a dev release, **even if there is no more recent point release** it tries to update the dev release module to the last official "point" release.

For example, I have heartbeat-dev installed (2012-Mar-20).  Yet when I run the `drush up` command, it prompts me to update to heartbeat 1.0 (2011-Jun-25).

If there is a newer dev release, I want to update to that.  If there is a newer point release, I want to update to that.  But if I have a dev release and the point release is older, I don't want to update.  How can I do this?

I've been handling this manually but as the number of modules on my site grows it's getting harder to keep track of which to update and which not to update...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, this sounds like a bug that should be addressed in the drush issue queue.  I'm guessing this is recent; it used to be that Drush would never go from dev to stable unless you used pm-download.  Now it is being a bit overzealous.

As a workaround, you can use the --lock option to stop Drush from updating the module at all (drush pm-update --lock=heartbeat), but this will also exclude newer dev releases as well.

Comment: I'll look into filing a bug report then.  But perhaps there is something wrong with my setup... I rolled back to Drush 4.5 and I had the same problem.  In fact, as far as I can remember I've also had this problem with Drush (user since v.3).

Comment: I located the source of the error-- On one module, the release notes information was wrong.  On another module, the version number of the dev number was wrong.  This lead me to my mistaken conclusion that drush was at issue.